# apply a function to each column of a DataFrame by group in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to apply a function to each column of my `DataFrame` but do so by group (MWE below). Is there a more elegant way of doing this than what I have?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {"a": [1,2,3,4,5], "b": [6,7,8,9,10]}, index = pd.Index([0,0,0,1,1], name="someindex"))
df1.groupby("someindex").apply(lambda g: g.apply(lambda x: np.average(x)))
```

This is just a toy example but the level of generality I had was one where the function can return the same shape as the group but uses all the elements in the computation (so standardizing the columns, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the more succinct way of doing things (for my example of standardizing the columns).  I post the `apply` way and then the `transform` way (which is the more succinct way).

```
#verbose
df1.groupby("someindex").apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: (y - y.mean())/y.std()))

#clear
df1.groupby("someindex").transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean())/x.std())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `groupby.mean`:

```
df1.groupby("someindex").mean()
```

This calculates average for all numeric columns by group.

Or for a general function, if it's aggregation in nature, `groupby.agg` can save you some `lambda`s:

```
df1.groupby("someindex").agg(np.average)
```

<sub>Depending on how general the function is, I guess there are cases where you can't simplify the solution</sub>

Comment: would like to use a general function, the mean was just a toy example...

Comment: I think it depends on what kind of function you are using. It would be helpful if you can be more explicit about it.

Comment: i'm simply playing around with pandas but the level of generality i had in mind is a function that returns the same shape as the group. so maybe one that standardizes each column, for example

Comment: It is unclear what you mean *returns the same shape as group*. @Psidom's answer returns exactly your post and more compactly.